# woocommerce get_order_report_data using date filter of meta key

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to extend woocommerce reports by showing admin a summary of products sold and their quantity, so far I have a successful result using the following code (I'm only showing the part where I got the query results from):

```
    $query_data = array(
      'jckwds_date' => array(
        'type'      => 'meta',
        'function'  => '',
        'name'      => 'delivery'
      ),
      '_product_id' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => '',
                'name' => 'product_id'
            ),
            '_qty' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => 'SUM',
                'name' => 'quantity'
      ),
      '_line_subtotal' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => 'SUM',
                'name' => 'gross'
            ),
    );
    $sales_orders_summary = $this->get_order_report_data( array(
      'data'                  => $query_data,
      'query_type'            => 'get_results',
      'group_by'              => 'product_id',
      'order_by'              => 'delivery ASC',
      'filter_range'          => false,
      'order_types'           => wc_get_order_types( 'order_count' ),
      'order_status'          => array( 'processing' ),
      'parent_order_status'   => false,
    ) );
```

and the html output is something like this:

```
         <?php 
            foreach( $sales_orders_summary as $order ) { 
          ?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $order->delivery; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo html_entity_decode(get_the_title($order->product_id)); ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $order->quantity; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo wc_price($order->gross); ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

And the results are as expected. BUT, what the admin would like to have now, is filter the result by the delivery date, which is a meta key of 'jckwds_date' as a result of third party plugin. It could be something like matching the built in woocommerce report custom range with the 'jckwds_date'.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hi @scubadude. I'm not sure how you are getting from part A to part B in your code blocks.  Where is `$sales_by_country_orders` coming from?

Comment: @HowardE, thanks for pointing that out! I feel so stupid, so sorry, not sure why i typed a different variable there... I edited the question, and hope this makes more sense now

Comment: So, you want to search by a range of `jckwds_date` from like where delivery date is between X and Y? And have that as the search range?  Which version of WC are you using? Since the 4.0 has totally new reports?

Comment: That is exactly right!, and I am using woocommerce 3.6.2, havent upgraded to 4 yet, Thanks!

Comment: oh and jckwds_date is only one date.

Comment: How would you expect the filter to work, and what is the output for `$order->delivery` is it a datetime? What does it look like.  I think if you add this to the question, it might help.

Comment: Thanks @HowardE ! $order->delivery will output a date ( a date of delivery picked by customer upon checkout), it is in format 'd/m/Y'

Comment: as a fellow diver, I'd like to help you but I don't think it's possible to figure out your issue due to the nature of your custom fields.  You might try passing the date into your function with a $_GET parameter, and in your foreach, if date !== whatever, continue.

Comment: @HowardE Thanks! What about $this->get_order_report_data() function, how do you use the where or where_meta condition? Any idea

Comment: @scubadude, I am doing the same thing like this,

 $where_meta[] = array(
  'meta_key' => '_shipping_delivery_date',
  'meta_value' => $start_order_date,
  'operator' => '>=',
  'type' => 'meta',
 );

 $where_meta[] = array(
  'meta_key' => '_shipping_delivery_date',
  'meta_value' => $end_order_date,
  'operator' => '<=',
  'type' => 'meta'
 );

But I am getting results of the previous year too, as there are no way to pass meta-type date in this. 

Did you get any solution for it?